# Android Studio Emulator cannot connect to network

Tags: android, connection, emulation

I had an emulator which I was using many times, but suddenly it stopped being able to get a connection, that's why I cannot test some apps.
I deleted it and I created more, with different Android versions and the same behavior

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlZGC.png)

if someone can help me to fix it, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.